# Unknown ethertypes 0x88e1 and 0x8912 from my Fritz Box

Tags: networking

At least every 15 minutes, but sometimes more frequently, I receive two broadcast packets with ethertypes 0x88e1 and 0x8912 sent from the MAC address of my Fritz Box. I can't find these ethertype values on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType#Examples) nor on [LiveAction Ethertype Values list](https://www.liveaction.com/glossary/ethertype-values/).

What protocol is that ? And where can I find a description of that protocol if not on Wikipedia ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x88e1 is HomePlug Management, for "Ethernet via powerline" bridges. The FritzBox might be looking to collect status information about the powerline network. (You can use *open-plc-utils* e.g. `plctool` or `int6kstat` to do the same from Linux.)

I'm not sure about 0x8912 but various posts say that it's also related to FritzBox's HomePlug functionality.

Related:

- https://pablo.tools/blog/computers/dropped-packets/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1015896/linux-server-dropping-rx-packets-in-netif-receive-skb-core
- https://docbox.etsi.org/Reference/homeplug_av21/homeplug_av21_specification_final_public.pdf
- [https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~nemo/plc/refs/HomePlug%20GP_Specification_Ch11_MMEs_v1.1-Jan_23_2012%20DRAFT.docx](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/%7Enemo/plc/refs/HomePlug%20GP_Specification_Ch11_MMEs_v1.1-Jan_23_2012%20DRAFT.docx)

Comment: After reading the linked articles and successfully implementing the netfilter solution from the first link, I think it's a shame that AVM does not provide a means to shut that useless traffic off. But my second question remains open: Where can I find a  description of those seemingly different protocols (HomePlug AV MME and mediaxtream) ?

Answer (score 2):

The official list of ethertype values is found on http://standards-oui.ieee.org/ethertype/eth.txt.

Comment: As of 2024, there is no protocol information for 88E1 and "mediaxtream" for 8912 on that list.